# Filtering rows of datagridview with text_changed when no specific datasource is attached

Tags: datagridview, rowfilter

Using the following code i can dynamicaly filter the rows of a datagridview that is connected with a datasource which is a datatable

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("userid like '%{0}%' or shortcut like '%{0}%' or command like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub
```

When i tried to use the same in a datagridview which is not connected whith a specific datasource but its rows where populated by using a loop such ass DataGridView2.Rows.Add(....) i get an object reference is not an instance of an object

Why is this happening;

Comment: I would think this would be obvious… if you manually filled the grid with data and the grid has no data source… then `DataGridView1.DataSource` would obviously be `null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I shouldn't ask why is this happening ... of course it is obvious! I apologize! My question was what is the equivalent syntax code in order to filter with the same way a datagridview that was manually filled.

Comment: Is there some reason you do not simply “add” an empty `DataSource` like a `DataTable` or `List<T>` to the grid before it is filled with data?

Comment: Yes , it is a diferent case. If i create and empty Datasource to the grid with the same columns and then add rows everytime you think the problem will be resolved ? I will give it a try and inform you